# Use of strcmp, initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

```
void check_vertical_win(char A[rows][columns]){
    int i,j;
    char *str1=A[i][j];
    char *str2=A[i-1][j];
    char *str3=A[i-2][j];
    char *str4=A[i-3][j];
    int elegxos1;
    int elegxos2;
    elegxos1=strcmp(str1,str2);
    elegxos2=strcmp(str3,str4);
    for(j=0;j<6;j++){
        for(i=6;i>=3;i--){
            if(elegxos1==0 && elegxos2==0){
                printf("\nBill is the winner.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to check if two strings in a matrix are equal,so i'm using the function strcmp. However the compiler gives warning: Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast.
(Then when i run the programme it says: Windows are checking for a solution at my problem).
I've tried a lot to find my mistake looking other similar programmes but i can't find out.

Comment: Which line is it referring to?

Comment: `char *str1=A[i][j];`............look closer....

Comment: `char *str1 = A[i][j];` this line (and the following 3 lines also) is already wrong and you'll get at least a compiler warning.

Comment: You've either failed to enable your compiler's warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra`) or failed to read and understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void check_vertical_win(char A[rows][columns])
```

This takes a matrix of chars. If you have a matrix where each entry is a string, it should be:

```
void check_vertical_win(char* A[rows][columns])
```

Also, you're using variables i and j before they are initialized (they contain garbage):

```
int i,j;
char *str1=A[i][j];
char *str2=A[i-1][j];
char *str3=A[i-2][j];
char *str4=A[i-3][j];
```

Comment: So how do you believe can i compare two or more strings without using strcmp or pointers(i'm a beginner at c programming)?

Comment: You have to use pointers, because C strings _are_ pointers. You can write your own string comparison, but unless your strings use encoding that standard library doesn't handle, you should stick to strcmp (or strncmp).

Comment: Let's say i do not want to find out if two strings are equal but i want to check if a string is equal to one string or another string.. How can i check that?Because strcmp can not do this..

Comment: Use strcmp twice. Compare strings x and y, then compare x and z.